# Callback function using variables calculated outside of it

Tags: php, anonymous-function

Basically I'd like to do something like this:

```
$arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
$avg = array_sum($arr) / count($arr);
$callback = function($val){ return $val < $avg };

return array_filter($arr, $callback);
```

Is this actually possible? Calculating a variable outside of the anonymous function and using it inside?

Answer (score 178, accepted):

You can use the `use` keyword to inherit variables from the parent scope. In your example, you could do the following:

```
$callback = function($val) use ($avg) { return $val < $avg; };
```

For more information, see the manual page on [anonymous functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

If you're running PHP 7.4 or later, [arrow functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php) can be used. Arrow functions are an alternative, more concise way of defining anonymous functions, which automatically capture outside variables, eliminating the need for `use`:

```
$callback = fn($val) => $val < $avg;
```

Given how concise arrow functions are, you can reasonably write them directly within the `array_filter` call:

```
return array_filter($arr, fn($val) => $val < $avg);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mfonda, I took a look at the manual page but missed that keyword in the code example.

Comment: Just to add to the above answer,  the parent scope variable are being COPIED rather than being made available inside the callback function. If the parent parameter needs to be manipulated, a reference should be sent like so

`$listOfValLessThanAvg = [];
$callback = function($val) use ($avg, &$listOfValLessThanAvg) 
{ 
   if( $val < $avg)
        array_push($listOfValLessThanAvg, $val);
 };`

Comment: Racking my brains on how to do this. First thought was `$GLOBALS` but obviously that's a no go. Came across this answer. Literally perfect.

Comment: Memory wise, which is more efficient? I remember that in Javascript, an arrow function will be instantiated at each call, whereas an anonymous one is created once and recalled for each iteration/calls, something like that, which means arrow function is less efficient albeit more practical. Is it also the case in PHP? I feel like I should post this as a separate question, although I don't think it's the case in PHP.

Answer (score -7):

use global variables i.e $GLOBAL['avg']

```
$arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
$GLOBALS['avg'] = array_sum($arr) / count($arr);
$callback = function($val){ return $val < $GLOBALS['avg'] };

$return array_filter($arr, $callback);
```

Comment: Global variables are considered bad practice. Moreover, using global vars here is an overkill, since `use` is suffice.

Comment: Global variables are evil!