# pass a callback WITH arguments in PHP

Tags: php, callback

I have a PHP library function expecting a callback with no arguments. 
I know I can pass an object's method with `array($this , 'my_function_name')` but how can I give parameters to the `my_function_name`? 
I have found a solution using `create_function` but from PHP manual I see it has security issues.

Comment: Wrap it with another function (presumably anonymous)

Comment: @zerkms - in that case the anonymous function would still get the argument from the "calling" library function. But I want to give it my own parameters.

Comment: Duplicate page which provides the advice found in the accepted answer below: [Callback function using variables calculated outside of it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4588714/2943403)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$that = $this;

$wrapper = function() use($that) {
    return $that->my_function_name('arg1', 'arg2');
};
```

Comment: It works but I think it requires php 5.3 .I am making a wordpress theme so "use" it's not ready for me yet.

Comment: @Emanuel Mocean: then you don't have other good choice other than creating a real method for that. `public function wrapper() ...`

Comment: In my particular case I still have to find a way to pass the parameters to the public function wrapper because the only time I know what I want to supply as a parameter to the callback is when I pass the callback. In other words I need the "use" part to make my local variables available in the callback .

Comment: To be more clear: what I am trying to do is pass the "rendering" callback to the add_submenu_page Wordpress function , and give that callback  a parameter so it knows what page to draw.

Comment: nevermind , I found a way reading ?page variable from $_GET[].

Answer (score 4):

There is a function called [call_user_func_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php).

```
call_user_func_array([$this, 'method'], $args);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on your library functions initiation of the callback method. You mentioned that you're making a wordpress theme. WP uses the `call_user_func` method typically. In your library function, use this function to invoke a call back with args, wrap a methods argument when calling it:

Callback Definition:

```
$callbackArg = "Got here";
defined_lib_func(array($this , 'my_function_name'), $callbackArg);
```

Library Script:

```
function defined_lib_function($callback, $args) {
  call_user_func($callback, $args);
}
```

for multiple arguments, just pass them as an array and define your callback method to accept an array as an argument.