# How to access the Variable in inner function PHP?

Tags: php, function, scope

How to access the variable in `inner` function of `outer` function variable?

I want to access `$arr` variable in the inner function.

```
<?php

function outer() {

    $arr = array();

    function inner($val) {

        global $arr;

        if($val > 0) {
            array_push($arr,$val);
        }
    }

    inner(0);
    inner(10);
    inner(20);

    print_r($arr);

}

outer();
```

**[codepad link](http://codepad.org/RnTUSguR)**

Comment: You have to use `Closures` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php)

Comment: Probably duplicate of [php - Callback function using variables calculated outside of it - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588714/callback-function-using-variables-calculated-outside-of-it)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This kind of "inner function" does not do what you probably expect. The global(!) function `inner()` will be defined upon calling `outer()`. This also means, calling `outer()` twice results in a "cannot redefine inner()" error.

As @hindmost pointed out, you need closures, functions that can get access to variables of the current scope. Also, while normal functions cannot have a local scope, closures can, because they are stored as variables.

*Your code with Closures:*

```
function outer() {

    $arr = array();

    $inner = function($val) use (&$arr) {
        if($val > 0) {
            array_push($arr,$val);
        }
    }

    $inner(0);
    $inner(10);
    $inner(20);

    print_r($arr);

}

outer();
```

Comment: Right way to do .. **+1** for closures !

Comment: @fab Thanks for your time. I got this error from your code. http://codepad.org/KLb20XSq

Comment: Looks like codepad runs on an ancient PHP version <= 5.2 - until now almost every hoster supports at least 5.3 which is the version where closures were introduced.

Answer (score 6):

Edited your code. You may want to refer to this

```
function outer() {

    $arr = array();

    function inner(&$arr,$val) { // pass array by reference
        if($val > 0) {
            array_push($arr,$val);
        }
    }

    inner($arr,0);
    inner($arr,10);
    inner($arr,20);

    print_r($arr);

}

outer();
```

You can pass `arr` by value, but you will not be able to print this

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10
    [1] => 20
)
```

Comment: why does this and not @fab 's answer has so many upvotes although his approach is a lot cleaner?

Answer (score 1):

First, do not use functions inside functions. Why? Because with this you'll get fatal error when triggering outer function second time (and that is because second run will invoke inner function declaration once again).

Second, if you need to do something with function result (as it stands from your code) - [`return`](https://www.php.net/return) that value. That is what is function intended to do - return some value. Another option may be [using reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) as a parameter (like in [`sort()`](https://www.php.net/sort) functions family) - but in normal situation you should avoid such behavior. This is side-effect and this makes code less readable in general.

Third, do not use [`global`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) variables. Because this binds your functions to your context, making your code totally unpredictable in terms of changing global context - and also impossible to scale to other contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Functions in php are all global.

If you want to access the global `$arr`, then you have to make it global too in `outer` function.

```
function outer() {

    global $arr;
    $arr = array();

    function inner($val) {

        global $arr;

        if($val > 0) {
            array_push($arr,$val);
        }
    }

    inner(0);
    inner(10);
    inner(20);

    print_r($arr);

}

outer();
```

There is an better way of doing this.

```
function outer() {

    $arr = array();

    $inner = function ($val) use (&$arr) {
        if($val > 0) {
           array_push($arr, $val);
        }
    };

    $inner(0);
    $inner(10);
    $inner(20);

    print_r($arr);

}

outer();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put `global` to the outer function.

```
function outer() {

    global $arr;
    $arr = array();

    function inner($val) {

        global $arr;

        if($val > 0) {
            array_push($arr,$val);
        }
    }

    inner(0);
    inner(10);
    inner(20);

    print_r($arr);

}
```

[Updated codepad.](http://codepad.org/J9PMjpaJ)