# Laravel 10 relation dynamic variable in subquery

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relation

How can I call a dynamic variable in a subquery?

I have some relations and call them like:

```
$locations = Location::query()
    ->with('brands', function ($query) {
        $query->with('employees')->where('location_id', {dynamic ID of brand location});
            })
    ->get();
```

The relation in the Location.php Class:

```
public function brands()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Brand::class);
}
```

The relation in the Brands.php Class:

```
public function employees()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Employee::class);
}
```

Without `->where('location_id', …)`, I get all employees that belong to the brand without considering the location.

Comment: where does `location_id` come from? If it comes from outside of the subquery scope you can use `use` keyword to pass it into the subquery scope. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22218563/10245455

Comment: It should come from the pivot table between location and brand. But I don't know how to get it from there

Comment: So at the point of this query, you _don't_ know what the `location_id` should be, but you do want to query based on a specific one? Can you explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: You questions isn't clear and confusing. Maybe helpful if you include the table structure to help understand where the FK (location_id) is referenced

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
$location_id_variable = 1;
$locations = Location::find(whateverid)
   ->with([
      'employees' => function($query) use ($location_id_variable) {
        ->query->where('location_id', $location_id_variable);
    }
 ])->get()
```

Comment: With this I get only one location don't I? I want all locations 

Comment: Is that not what you want. I guess your question is unclear to me - your showing passing a location id in your question. Otherwise change your relationship to hasMany