# Add variable's value after each sequence of letters in a string using preg_replace_callback()

Tags: php, regex, callback, scope, preg-replace-callback

How can I pass a variable into the custom callback function of a `preg_replace_callback()` call?

For example, I'd like to use the variable `$add` within my callback function:

```
private function addToWord($add) {
    return preg_replace_callback(
        '/([a-z])+/i',
        function($word, $add) {
            return $word.$add;
        },
        $this->text
    );
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`use` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065188/in-php-5-3-0-what-is-the-function-use-identifier) here:

```
private function addToWord($add) {
    return preg_replace_callback(
        '/([a-z])+/i',
        function($word) use ($add) {
            return $word[1] . $add;
        },
        $this->text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `use` is not needed for your task; neither is `preg_replace_callback()` or the capture group in your pattern.

Match your sequence of letters, then forget them with `\K`, then inject the `$add` value to the string at the position just after the sequence of letters.

```
private function addToWord($add)
{
    return preg_replace('/[a-z]+\K/i', $add, $this->text); 
}
```

Otherwise, this question is a duplicate of [Callback function using variables calculated outside of it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4588714/2943403).